# What is the proper way to update a news feed that frequently appears and disappears?

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate, viewdidappear

I appreciate the many entry points the iOS SDK offers for developers to update their UI...(`viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive`, etc.) but oftentimes I wonder if I am refreshing data in my view controllers too often. For example, I have a news feed on my home screen that needs to be updated frequently. I have my data fetching method in `viewDidAppear` because users switch back and forth between the news feed and another tab. However, I also have the data fetching method called via `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` for when the app wakes up from background on the news feed view controller. So with that in mind the data will be fetched twice each time the news feed view controller loads for the first time.

My question is, is this tactic problematic? If so, is there a more efficient way to fetch my data that will still allow me to update my view frequently?

Answer (score 1):

It seems redundant to have the data fetched in `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` and in `viewDidAppear`, but other than that there is no big problem with it.

A way to receive your feed updates more reliably would be to implement silent push notifications that are sent from the server every time there are changes on the your feed.

Comment: Would my app need to be active in order for the notification to update the feed? I would rather use an approach like this instead of relying on the view delegate methods to update things like new friend requests, or new posts in my news feed.